# How to select menu option after right clicking on folder executing python script in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, scripting, pywinauto

```
import pywinauto

pywinauto.Application().Start(r'explorer.exe')
```

Comment: You mean after opening the `File explorer` you want to open `My computers` ? Please clarify what `menu` you want to see.

Comment: I mean when we right-click on any folder we get a menu so I want to select option such cut, copy, rename, properties by writing a python script

Comment: If its not necessary to it using python, I can recommend you a software to do GUI automation. It's much powerful and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool that I use while doing stuff is inspect.exe (built in windows tool). If you look at the menu whilst using this tool, you can often see that that menu is technically part of the desktop (not part of the application). The way that I get to those items is:

```
    import pywinauto

    desk = pywinauto.Desktop()
    desk.Menu.child_window(title="Cut", control_type="MenuItem").click_input()
```

It's the same with all of the menu items just replace the title with which command you want cut, copy, rename, paste, etc.